# MySql GROUP_CONCAT with GROUP BY every set of nth rows

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7f72/2

Assume a table called testt has 10 records in it (id is not null auto increment).  If I were to do

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM testt
```

I would expect the results to look like

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

How could I get the results to look like this:

1,2

3,4

5,6

7,8

9,10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to group by a function of the `id`.  Something like this:

```
select group_concat(id order by id)
from testt
group by floor((id - 1) / 2)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you!  I will accept it as the answer in 9 minutes when SO let's me.  Care to add an explanation?

Comment: I applied this to some of my live tables, and I realized this solution only works if there are no gaps in your Id column.  If you have id's 1-5 then 15-30, it does not function properly.  I'll edit my question with the answer when I figure out a solution.

Comment: @user2278120 . . . You should ask another question, with an explicit mention of the gaps (and even a reference back to this question).

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I already figured it out.  Are you sure I should create a question I already know the answer to?

Comment: @user2278120 . . . My point is not to ask a question in a comment, but as a question (this is a grey area . . . little questions are appropriate for comments).

Comment: @user2278120 you are perfectly welcome to ask and self-answer the new question if you already have the answer and your question is unique to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone should run into this problem, but need it work on an id column that is not sequential, here is the solution.

In the below query **test** is the table name with the non sequential id column.  And **Dbname** is optional if you already have your db selected.

```
SELECT  
   GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id ASC) AS "ids" 
FROM  
(  
    SELECT  
    @row := @row +1 AS rownum, id
    FROM  
    (  
    SELECT @row :=0 
    ) r, Dbname.test 
) ranked  
GROUP BY 
    FLOOR((rownum - 1) / 2);
```

If you have a table that looks like this:

```
id
1
2
3
4
10
15
17
18
20
21
23
25
32
55
105
1011
1012
1013
1014
1111
1112
1113
1114
1115
1116
1117
1118
1119
2001
2002
2003
```

The above query will give the results like this:

```
ids
1,2
3,4
10,15
17,18
20,21
23,25
32,55
105,1011
1012,1013
1014,1111
1112,1113
1114,1115
1116,1117
1118,1119
2001,2002
2003
```

And finally if you changed this line

```
FLOOR((rownum - 1) / 2);
```

to

```
 FLOOR((rownum - 1) / 3);
```

The results would like this:

```
ids
1,2,3
4,10,15
17,18,20
21,23,25
32,55,105
1011,1012,1013
1014,1111,1112
1113,1114,1115
1116,1117,1118
1119,2001,2002
2003
```

Hope that helps someone.